# csv module => DictReader class Reader Object: why can't I iterate through Reader Object with file closed, but I can access its attributes?

Tags: python, csv, filereader

This might be a silly question, but I am confused by the following: I created a reader object out of a DictReader class of the csv module.

The following code returns an error because the csv file is already closed as the for loop is not indented:

```
import csv
with open(file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

returns this error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

However, I am able to run commands to get the reader's attributes, such as:

```
reader.fieldnames
reader.line_num
```

What is the logic for this? I am confused as to why I can access the reader's attributes, but no longer iterate through it. Also, I would have thought that once that I assign:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

I should be able to access the reader's contents even with the file closed.

Comment: If you didn't specify `fieldnames` when creating the `DictReader`, trying to access this attribute will make your `reader` try to get them from the first line of the file, and will fail with `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csv.DictReader` (and `csv.reader` as well) are built taking a file handle object as parameter. It doesn't copy the handle, or read the entire contents of the file at once, or such things.

When you exit the `with` block, this file handle is closed and when `csv.DictReader` object tries to access it, it stumbles on the "closed file" exception. Note that the `with` block applies to the raw file handle, not to the `csv.DictReader` object.

The `csv.DictReader` object still exists and is valid, but is no longer useable to read data since its source file handle has been invalidated.

That's no different of the simpler example below:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,source):
        self.source = source
    def bar(self):
        print(self.source)

lst = [1,2,3]
f = Foo(lst)
f.bar()  # prints [1, 2, 3]
lst.clear()
f.bar()  # prints []
```

Above, as soon as `lst` is cleared, the `f` object loses its ability to print the list, even if the `f` object itself remains valid.

If you want to keep the contents, you have to force iteration on the file, in a separate `list` object if you want to keep the reader attributes handy:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
contents = list(reader)
```

Comment: Thanks, this all made sense. What I still find surprising/good to know is that even though I can no longer use the object to read data, I can still access attributes such as fieldnames. I am assuming it's just a matter of memory use.